# ExtJS: Adding a button to dynamic content odd behavior

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers and ExtJS together. In a map, I have popups that appear when you interact with the map. The HTML for the these popups contains a container that I use to create an extjs button with a menu.

When you close the popup or click out of the menu/button, the menus don't disappear. Once the button is clicked to show the menu, it remains visible! To resolve, I can write some code to manually destroy it - but I'm only firing this code on the popup close. Does anyone know why the button w/ menu is acting this way?

I init the button and menu when a popup is created on the map:

```
Map.popupMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
    id: "ChangesGridContextMenu",
    items: [{ .... }]
});

Map.popupButton = new Ext.Button({
    id: "popupActions",
    text: "Actions..",
    menu: Map.popupMenu
});
```

When the popup is closed I destroy the extjs components:

```
if (Map.popupMenu !== null) {
    Map.popupMenu.destroy();
    Map.popupMenu = null;
}
if (Map.popupButton !== null) {
    Map.popupButton.destroy();
    Map.popupButton = null;
}
```

Comment: I thought this might be a bit of a niche question ;)

Comment: Is Map an ExtJS object or not?

Comment: No, its just an object literal I'm using - not part of any lib

Comment: How do you show yours popups?